# image show in jquery datatable in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery

I want show images in my datatable. Note that I can show all data except images  in the datatable. I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 in my application. Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var oTable = $('#tblPromobanner').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
      "url": "/PromoBanner/loaddata",
      "type": "GET",
      "datatype": "json"
    },
    "responsive": true,
    "columns": [
      { "data": "DepartmentID", "autoWidth": true },
      { "data": "ContentId", "autoWidth": true },
      { "data": "nav_url", "autoWidth": true },
      //{ "data":"img_src", render: getImg }
      {
        "data": "img_src",
        "render": function (url, type, full) {
          return '<img height="75%" width="75%" src="' + full[3] + '"/>';
        }
      }
    ]
  });
```

Here is my controller code

```
public ActionResult loaddata()
{
  db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
  var clientes = db.Promobanner.ToList();
  return Json(new { data = clientes }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you show the actual rendered html?

Comment: what is the html where you are loading datatable ? did you check by placing a debugger in render of image function? And are you seeing any error? What about in DOM, is it rendering or giving some error?

Comment: yes I'm using table and this datatable show dynamic image . I debuged i can see the image path property name "img_src" in  render function

Comment: Can you post one of the row img HTML from developer tool (F12)?

Comment: I hope this is what you asked     ContentId
:
123421
Department
:
null
DepartmentID
:
1
id
:
3
img_src
:
"~/Images/26165276_535425736823406_3407553106805478901_n.jpg"
nav_url
:
"wap.bongobd.com"
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: When i debug in render funtion inside full I get this

Comment: So hoping that this is getting rendered on UI aswell. I also wanted you to check by inspecting your datatable image column and post what is the HTML that is being displayed